# Invert dictionary by Using dictionary as parameters in function

Tags: python

I am working on a Mooc exercise that asks to invert the dictionary in a function without returning the value.

Please **I** write a function named invert(dictionary: dict), which takes a dictionary as its argument. The dictionary should be inverted in place so that values become keys and keys become values.

An example of its use:

```
s = {1: "first", 2: "second", 3: "third", 4: "fourth"}
invert(s)
print(s)
```

Expected output:

```
{"first": 1, "second": 2, "third": 3, "fourth": 4}
```

My code:

```
def invert(dictionary: dict):
    dictionary={v:k for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```

every time I run the code with the above-mentioned example it prints out the same global dictionary instead of an inverted one.

output from my code:

```
{1: "first", 2: "second", 3: "third", 4: "fourth"}
```

Comment: You need to return `dictionary` and use `print(invert(s))` since dictionary is not changed in place.

Comment: Save the dictionary's items, then iterate over the items (don't use `for k,v in d.items()`, use `for k,v in saved_items`), set `d[v] = k` then `del d[k]`. Alternatively, use the comprehensions shown in the answers, then `d.clear()` then `d.update(new_d)`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return from the `invert` function and directly print it.

```
def invert(dictionary):
    return {v: k for k, v in dictionary.items()}


s = {1: "first", 2: "second", 3: "third", 4: "fourth"}
print(invert(s))
```

Comment: This does not invert the dictionary in-place